# How to get and set class fields in class methods

Tags: c++

I have an `.h` file that describes the fields and methods of the class. The implementation of the methods is located in the `.cpp` file. For example, I have 2 fields:

```cpp
int x = 0; 
int y = 0;
```

And setters and getters for them.

On pressing a button on the form, If I want the value of the field to change, for example, `x = y + 15`, how do I need to access the fields?  Is there a difference?

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_PBtn_clicked() //this function is also a member of the class
{
    x = y + 15;
    //or 
    setX(getY() + 15);
    //or
    this->setX(this->getY() + 15);
}
```

Comment: `x = y + 15;` Member functions can see all class members. No getter/setter use required.

Comment: *is there a difference?* By the time a half-decent compiler's done there should be no difference.

Comment: @user4581301 "*No getter/setter use required*" - unless the setter has side effects (updating other fields, firing events, etc) and you want the change of `x` to trigger those side effects.

Comment: To be honest, I stripped a discussion of that from the comment to keep it simple. I figure if the asker had code other than the assignment or the return statement in their accessors they wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Mind you if they're coming in from a language with Delphi-like properties I can see a potential source of confusion.

Comment: Please clarify __why__ you wants get/set. I think that's the real problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to answer in terms of C#. C# has properties that make usage of members and setters/getters similar syntactically. Creation of setters/getters are easy. And because the cost of usage of properties are low it's usually preferable to use properties. **Because coder can add some data verification of input, etc. later with less efforts** and encapsulate these verification or triggering of events in one place. C++ require more efforts to read code with setters/getters because of function call syntax. If I want to make code more readable (for instance the code of some algorithm) I will use members directly. often I pass members as parameters - this functional style make function reuse easier. In case I expect some verification I use getters/setters. So there is no one rule - it depends. From performance perspective there is no need to use members directly because methods may be `inline`.